# How can I reverse functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a website and I want dark mode to be toggled on and off. I've searched for how to reverse functions, but since I suck at JavaScript I couldn't set the function to reverse it. So I'm trying to reverse this here:

```
<label class="switch">
  <input id="input" onclick="changeColor(); changeColo(); changeCol(); changeCo(); changeC();" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

var colors = ["#2D2D2D"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColor() {
        var col = document.getElementById("body");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
    var colors = ["#332e2e"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeColo() {
        var col = document.getElementById("article");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
    var colors = ["#332e2e"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeCol() {
        var col = document.getElementById("button");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
    var colors = ["#332e2e"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeCo() {
        var col = document.getElementById("div");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
    var colors = ["#2D2D2D"];
    var colorIndex = 0;
    function changeC() {
        var col = document.getElementById("form-container");
        if( colorIndex >= colors.length ) {
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex++;
    }
```

That's what I need to reverse. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you an example with your code and you could work out the rest.

```js
var colors = ["#2D2D2D"]; // I don’t know why you have an array of
// color, but I could get this to be much simpler without using
// array, but I followed your example to make it simpler for you
var colorIndex = 0;
function changeColor() {
    var col = document.getElementById("body");
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length) {
        colorIndex = 0;
    }

    if (colors[colorIndex] == col.getAttribute("currentColor")) {

        col.style.backgroundColor = null; // Take the CSS color
        col.setAttribute("currentColor",col.style.backgroundColor);
    }
    else {
        col.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
        col.setAttribute("currentColor", colors[colorIndex]);
    }

    colorIndex++;
}
```

```css
#body{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <label class="switch">
        <input id="input" onclick="changeColor();" type="checkbox">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable to handle states, set a Boolean initial value and update its value every time your toggle button is clicked, for example:

```js
let actived = false;

function setState(){
  if(actived == false){
    changeColor1();
    actived = true;
  } else {
    changeColor2();
    actived = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" (onclick)="setState()"/>
```

Comment: Looks like the `else` block was missing `actived = false;`, which I just added.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

Approach 1:

Define separate styles for light and dark themes. Set the class on body as per the required theme

JavaScript:

```
function toggleTheme() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.toggle('light');
   document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.toggle('dark');
}
```

CSS:

```
body.light {
   background-color: white;
   color: black;
}
body.light button {
   background-color: blue;
   color: black;
}

body.dark{
   background-color: black;
   color: white;
}
body.dark button {
   background-color: grey;
   color: black;
}
```

Approach 2:

Define variable properties and use these n your app for styling

JavaScript:

`Same as above`

CSS:

```
body.light {
  --color: black;
  --backgroundColor: white;
}
body.dark {
 --color: white;
 --backgroundColor: black;
}
button {
  color: var(--color);
  background-color: var(--backgroundColor);
}
```